# Проверка наличия атрибута и удаление его по клику если был найден

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как c jQuery сделать проверку на наличие в элементе атрибута и в случае если атрибут найден при клике по данному элементу этот атрибут удалить

Например:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="confirm_agree" checked />
```

`input` - элемент

`checked` - атрибут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input[checked]').click(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="confirm_agree" checked>
```